# Context menus flash rainbow colors before menu appears

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, context-menu, right-click

This is one of the strangest Windows bugs I've experienced.  All of my context menus appear as animated color-wheels for a split second before the real menu appears:

[image: Animation of context menu opening]

What could be causing this behavior?  I'm mainly just curious about any implementation details that might be causing this laser show.  I'm guessing I can fix this by fiddling with my graphics card driver.

I'm running Windows 8.1 on a Dell Studio 1747 with an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 560v graphics card.

**- EDIT -**

The patterns that appear in the animation above are artifacts of the GIF - the actual colors transition smoothly:

[image]

Comment: As far as bugs go, that's pretty awesome. Now I'm fascinated by the patterns in the colour spectrum. How are those semi-regular "cells" formed? You can see at the right and bottom edges, the pattern resolves into horizontal (resp. vertical) bands. As the bands move away from the edges, their edges become jagged, but they're still identifiable as distinct layers. The intersection of the horizontal and vertical bands form "cells", although they tend to look more like diamonds or triangles than rectangles due to the jagged boundaries.

Comment: @pyrocrasty Actually, those patterns are just artifacts of the GIF - the real colors transition smoothly.  I edited my question to show a screenshot without the GIF noise.

Comment: Ah, okay. That's a much more boring bug, albeit still colourful. I'm still curious about those artifacts, though. Maybe it's the result of the software discretizing the spectrum into a limited palette to reduce image size. Btw, judging from [this shot](http://i.imgur.com/iH6YTzI.png), it looks like a red-yellow vertical spectrum appears first, then a green-yellow horizontal spectrum sweeps in from left to right. I don't know if that's significant...

Answer (score 0):

Try installing a newer or older ATI Radeon driver to see if you can isolate it to the specific video card driver you are currently using.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).